# How to make a numeric matrix out of a non-numeric one (or workaround)

Tags: r, matrix, spatial

When I try to calculate a distance matrix and a corresponding weights matrix with the ***spacom package*** in R, I encounter the following problem (find [here](https://gist.github.com/lessermatter/0284be117a19620750aa) a replicable example):

```
> distmatrix <- DistanceMatrix(mafialomb, "NOME_COM", longlat = FALSE)
> weights <- WeightMatrix(distmatrix, 5000000)
> is.numeric(distmatrix)
TRUE
> is.numeric(weights)
FALSE
```

In order to proceed with the estimation, **I need the weights matrix to be numeric**. R Studio tells me that the *distmatrix* is data, while *weights* is a "*Formal class dsCMatrix*" and falls under "Values". When I call:

```
> head(weights)
```

I get the following description:

> 6 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

Do you know of:

- any way to **make this matrix numeric**; or
- **any other method** to calculate spatial weights **that would output a numeric weights matrix**?

Comment: Your linked data is full of S4 polygon objects which haven't come out in the dput.

Comment: Hi Nick - if I understand your comment correctly: the data is a shapefile, extracted through the _getinfo.shape_ function in the _maptools_ package. When I dput it, the output includes those "S4 polygon objects" specifications. Is there any way I could avoid that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, there's probably a way to overcome the problem: just give me a minute and I'll amend my first post and data.

Comment: (Quick-)fixed the replicable example. Hopefully now someone may come up with a solution! :)

Comment: @Frank: I followed your advice, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
nWeights <- as.matrix(weights)
is.numeric(nWeights)
#TRUE
```